# How to iterate over a dictionary to make new for loop for the remaining elements?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to make a new dictionary from the one which I'm having.

```
`dict1 = {'A':{}, 'B':{}, 'C':{}, 'D':{}, 'E':{}}
 for key, val in dict1.iteritems():
    mytest = key
    newConditionFlag = getSummary(mytest)
    if newConditionFlag == 1:
        make dict2`
```

where getSummary function is as follows:

```
`def getSummary(mytest):
    newConditionFlag==0
    bVal = mytest.CanClose()
    if bVal == True:
        pass
    else:
        newConditionFlag=1
    return newConditionFlag`
```

If newConditionFlag == 1 for B, then my dict2 should be

`dict2 = 'C':{}, 'D':{}, 'E':{}}`. 
In the same way if newConditionFlag == 1 for C,

`dict2 = 'D':{}, 'E':{}}`.
How should I do this?

I know for a simple condition if we want to access remaining values what we do is

```
`l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i,j in zip(l, l[2:]):
    print j`
```

But what should be done in case of dictionary? If we try it the same way it gives `TypeError: unhashable type`

Comment: The concept of *"from that point"* makes no sense - dictionaries are **unordered**. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: as mentioned by @jonrsharpe dictionary is unordered, you may want to use: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict but it's hard to tell if it's any good for what you do

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the code, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could possibly make sense is to convert the dictionary to a list first. Do your processing on the list, then convert back to a dictionary.

```
l = sorted(dict1.items())
# do your thing
dict1 = dict(l)
```